# How to run an app shortcut or a tasker task when battery temperature is above a custom threshold?

Tags: applications, battery, tasker

At high temperature:

- I can trigger an alaram  using [Battery Bot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro&hl=en).
- Turn off data/wifi/bluetooth etc., using [Battery Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.batterytasker&hl=en).

But I want to do many things like:

- Turn off data when temperature is above 40.
- Turn on it when battery temperature drops to 30, only if it was turned off due to temperature (other wise do nothing ) and the data plan is not expired.

**Question**

I would like to achieve aforementioned tasks using [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate&hl=en) ([Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) like app supports tasker plugins).

Is there any app that monitors battery temperature and runs an app shortcut (and thus a Tasker/Automate task)? (What about launching an app, creating a file?)

In other words, I need an alternative for Tasker plugin(paid) [Battery Temperature Detection](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kanetik.battery_temperature&hl=en).

**Note:**

My phone doesn't support CPU temperature, and neither Tasker nor Automate supports battery temperature.

OS: ICS , Non Rooted.

Comment: Is your phone rooted, or can you afford to root your phone? I might suggest a solution but possibly could require root access. Which Android version are you running and what is the device name?

Comment: Thaks for the resppnse. Non rooted. I found a method using shell commands and parsing the output. Unfortunately it does't work on non root devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Broadcast receive" block with "Battery changed" action, the broadcast "extras" will include a "temperature" entry:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html#EXTRA_TEMPERATURE

Here's an example flow for getting the battery temperature:
http://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/655

Comment: promising but example flo is not compatable in my version. Trying with the corrent ver, but not much info about app broadcast.

Comment: Unfortunately flow freeze aTbroadcast module . even change in battery level  make any flow.